# Passing all the variables defined in a class from different file to another python file

Tags: python, oop, aws-cdk

I have few variables defined in a python file['apppythonfile.py'] under 'class appstack(cdk.Stack)' . I need to utilize or pass these variables in another class [ class GenStack(cdk.Stack) ] in another Python file ['Genpythonfile.py']. I tried below code to do it.

```
class GenStack(cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope:cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, appstack, construct_id, **kwargs)
##tryed calling the 'SGnode' variable defined in appstack class

        print (appstack.SGnode)
```

After executing this I got

```
TypeError: __init() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 positional arguments ( and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

Instead I tried importing the whole file like this also

```
from apppythonfile import *
class GenStack(cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope:cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope,construct_id, **kwargs)
          
# tried printing a variable from apppythonfile.py file
        print (SGnode)
```

Then got

```
NameError: name 'SGnode' is not defined
```

SGnode is declared like below in apppythonfile.py

```
class appstack(cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope:cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope,construct_id, **kwargs)
#Varibles defined for further use 
        vpcID=vpc-6895xxxxxx
        vpc_declared=ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self,"vpctouse",vpc_id=vpcID)
        SGnode = ec2.SecurityGroup(self,"securitygroup of nodes", vpc=vpc_declared, securirt_group_name="prod-node-sg", allow_all_outbound=True)
```

I am new to Oops concepts and aws-cdk. How should I declare it in Genpythonfile.py to call the variables from different class and apppythonfile.py python file.

Comment: how is SGnode defined in apppy script?

Comment: @rv.kvetch Added the code showing how I have defined SGnode

Comment: try not passing in `appstack` to `super().__init__()`

Comment: I tried it. I have added the code where I tried without adding appstack above. I got the nameerror for that

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood , you want inherit all variables/methods from a class of a different file, right?
In this case :

```
from apppythonfile import appstack
class GenStack(appstack):
#your code
```

This is called Inheritance which allows you to define a class that inherits all the methods and properties from another class. In this case, the *parent class is appstack* whereas the *child class is GenStack*.

> EDIT : It seems like that you forgot to add "__" after "__init" , it should
> be
>
> `__init__`

Comment: Tried this. Still got the same "NameError" mentioned above in the question.

Comment: Could you post the code of appstack?

Comment: Can you please see the last part in the question, I have added the code from appstack

Comment: See the edit, you made a tiny mistake in the syntax

Comment: Sorry while copying here, I left it by mistake. I fixed it in the question now. Still getting the undefined error